# Interpreting Logistic Regression Categorical Coefficients

Tags: regression, self-study, logistic, interpretation, regression-coefficients

So I have this question:

If we fit a logistic regression with categorical predictor X with categories A, B and C, and have the estimated coefficients β0=−2.5 and βB=0.5 and βA=−0.2.

(a)  Interprete eˆβB,eˆβA and eˆβ0.
(b)  Which categorical would cause, on average, the smallest odds of success?

This was my interpretation:

a.

eβˆB is the marginal effect on the odds ratio of being in category B rather than in category C.

e^βA is the marginal effect on the odds ratio of being in category A rather than in category C.

e^β0 is the marginal effect on the odds ratio of being in category C rather than in categories A and B.

b. Category C would on average cause the smallest chance of success. This is because it has the smallest marginal effect at e^−2.5 = 0.082, which means it has the smallest effect on the odds-ratio compared to categories A and B. The marginal effect of A and B on the odds-ratio are 0.8187 and 1.649 respectively.

Is this correct or am I completely off?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to CV. If this is a homework problem, please use the Self-Study tag. Note that we're not here to do your homework for you, but we can help you if you're stuck.

Comment: Also the values you gave are impossible; `e^x` cannot be negative.

Comment: Yeah my bad there was a typo, I was just wondering if the interpretation I gave it correct.